# Why is assigning print() to a variable not a syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I discovered that I can do this (Python 3.6.1):

```
my_var = print('test')
```

This immediately prints `test` but the variable remains empty. Shouldn't this be a syntax (or other) error? I guess it's the same as doing `my_var = None` but it feels dirty.

Comment: It should be a syntax error just because it feels dirty to you?

Comment: You can go even further and do `my_var = print`, and then use `my_var("test")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign any function's return to a variable, if it doesn't return anything, the default value is `None`.

Actually, there are the same.

```
def a():
    # return nothing
    pass

b = a()
# b is None
```

So this is not a special situation but just a common syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Every python function returns something. If not specified explicitly, it returns `None`. `print` is a function, so everything is allright.

Answer (score 2):

`print` is a function and it returns `None` on successful execution. That's why you get `my_var` as `None`.

Answer (score 2):

**In Python 2.7**, `print` was a statement. So you cannot assign that to a variable.

**In Python 3.x**, print is a function (which needs to be invoked with parenthesis). However every function return something even if it does not have any return statement it will return `None`

In your case print will return `None`, so there's not much point in assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

In **python 2** `print` is statement, so it will be syntax error.

In **python 3** `print` is function.

Every function in python returns value. If no return statement, it will return None. so `my_var = print('test')` is valid python3 statement.